# how to stop rendering a component inside app.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

```
<div className='App'>
  <SideBar />
  <Routes>

    <Route path='/' element={<Body />}>
      <Route path='/' element={<Home />} />
      <Route path='setting' element={<Setting />} />
    </Route>

    <Route path='/service' element={<ServiceLayout />}>
      <Route path='/service' element={<Service />} />
    </Route>
  </Routes>

  <Article />
</div>
```

I don't want to render the article component while I am in service component. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

The `Article` component is ***unconditionally*** rendered under the routed content.

```
<div className='App'>
  <SideBar />
  <Routes>
    <Route element={<Body />}>
      <Route path='/' element={<Home />} />
      <Route path='setting' element={<Setting />} />
    </Route>

    <Route path='/service' element={<ServiceLayout />}>
      <Route index element={<Service />} />
    </Route>
  </Routes>

  <Article /> // <-- always rendered!
</div>
```

Trivial solution is to just remove `Article` from the JSX:

```
<div className='App'>
  <SideBar />
  <Routes>
    <Route element={<Body />}>
      <Route path='/' element={<Home />} />
      <Route path='setting' element={<Setting />} />
    </Route>

    <Route path='/service' element={<ServiceLayout />}>
      <Route index element={<Service />} />
    </Route>
  </Routes>

  {/* <Article /> removed */}
</div>
```

This probably isn't what you are actually wanting though. Another option is to ***conditionally*** render it on a route.

Example:

```
<div className='App'>
  <SideBar />
  <Routes>
    <Route element={<Body />}>
      <Route path='/' element={<Home />} />
      <Route path='setting' element={<Setting />} />
    </Route>

    <Route path='service' element={<ServiceLayout />}>
      <Route index element={<Service />} />
    </Route>
  </Routes>

  <Route path='article' element={<Article /> } /> // <-- only on "/article" path
</div>
```